# Iterating through nodes named with increasing number

Tags: xslt

I'm learning XSLT and I have following XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>

<ROWSET>
 <nazwa>nazwa d</nazwa>
 <ROW>
  <NAME>Kwota bieżąca</NAME>
  <SCHEDULE>0</SCHEDULE>
  <UNDISPOSED>0</UNDISPOSED>
  <FSUM>0</FSUM>
  <DAYS>
      <DAY1>5</DAY1>
      <DAY2>4</DAY2>
      <DAY3>3</DAY3>
      <DAY4>2</DAY4>
      <DAY5>1</DAY5>
  </DAYS>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

So the node name is changing And I need to itearate through all days so i had `5 4 3 2 1` in output. I have no idea how to do this. I think I have to use xsl:for-each somehow.

Can this template work?

```
<xsl:template name="dni_miesiaca_dane">
        <xsl:param name="count"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="drukuj_liczbe">
            <xsl:with-param name="wartosc"
                select="/ROWSET/ROW/DAYS/DAY[$count]" />
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 31">
            <xsl:call-template name="dni_miesiaca_dane">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count+1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

I don't know how to replace DAY1, DAY2 etc to make it work. `DAY[$count]` doesn't work...

Comment: Have a look at the [`xsl:sort`](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc/xsl_sort_design.html) element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xslt 1 you could do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- ... just continue in processing... -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ROWSET/ROW/DAYS/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ... if you find node with name starting with DAY put its content to the output -->
    <xsl:template match="node()[starts-with(name(),'DAY')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In xslt 2 it could be even easier

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/ROWSET/ROW/DAYS/node()[starts-with(name(),'DAY')]" separator=" " />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath address `/ROWSET/ROW/DAYS/*` will give you all child elements and you get them in document order.  Is there a reason you need to address them by name?